# Why an internal error in ORTE return code is 0?

Tags: python, c++, mpi, openmpi

While using OpenMPI and running tests with gtest I am getting the following error:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKbBb.png)

I understand the error, but since it is returning a return code 0 gtest is returning a pass result and I cannot indicate when the error is appearing.

How can I detect the error when it occurs?

I tried to search a env var a flag to find the error but cannot find any..

Comment: Sounds like a bug you should report to the Open MPI developers.